# Use epigrafica font for sections, otherwise newtxtext,newtxmath?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, times

I'd like to use epigrafica specifically for chapters and sections, but like to use times font for main texts.

```
\usepackage{epigrafica}          % for chapter/section
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % for main text
```

Is there any way to do this? I can only use pdftex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example compilable (including documentclass, necessary packages and document environment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `epigrafica` package does nasty things because the fonts are not really following an established encoding. However, here you are:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epigrafica}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\allsectionsfont{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{epigrafica}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Titl\'e}

\section{Titl\'e}

Some text with m\'ath $e^{\log x}=x+y-y$

\end{document}
```

I added some accents because that's where `epigrafica` does the nasty things.

[image]

With the `memoir` class, you can add the font selection to the appropriate hooks.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epigrafica}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\epigraficafont}{%
  \fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{epigrafica}\selectfont
}

\appto{\chaptitlefont}{\epigraficafont}
\appto\secheadstyle{\epigraficafont}
\appto\subsecheadstyle{\epigraficafont}
\appto\subsubsecheadstyle{\epigraficafont}
\appto\paraheadstyle{\epigraficafont}
\appto\subparaheadstyle{\epigraficafont}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Titl\'e}

\section{Titl\'e}

Some text with m\'ath $e^{\log x}=x+y-y$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Let's hope the OP doesn't use a KOMA class...

Comment: Thank you! But I got an error: `"The sectsty package doesn't work with this document class.` I use memoir class.

Comment: @yhorie You're out of luck then. `;-)` Please, always add the important details to your questions; the document class *is* a very important detail.

Comment: @yhorie I added the necessary code

Comment: Thanks, @egreg! It worked perfectly. Also, sorry for not providing details on the class.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. When I put
`\RequirePackage{amsmath}`
`\RequirePackage{epigrafica}`
`\RequirePackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`
in my class file, I got errors:
`Command \medspace already defined.`
`Package xkeyval Error: xkeyval loaded before \documentclass.`
seemingly due to the incompatibility with `memoir`. Is there any workaround to suppress these?

Comment: @yhorie No code, no idea.

Comment: Sorry... this is the minimum code to reproduce the errors:

`\RequirePackage{amsmath}`
`\RequirePackage{epigrafica}`
`\RequirePackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`
`\documentclass{memoir}`
`\usepackage{etoolbox}`
`\begin{document}`
`text`
`\end{document}`
`

Comment: @yhorie And why should you use `\RequirePackage` in that way?

Comment: I actually have these `\RequirePackage{}` in a different *.cls file, in which I like to use `epigrafica` font. Isn't this a right way?

Comment: @yhorie Well, I can't guess what you're doing. This can be the object of a new question.

Comment: @egreg I started a new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380904/loading-epigrafica-sty-in-a-class-file-master-class-is-memoir-shows-duplicated). Thanks again for answering the questions!