# Epigrafica font for sections and chapter using pdflatex

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

I want to use epigrafica font as "sans serif" in sections and chapters but I don't have any idea how to do it. I found here a solution in pdftex. Is there a chance to do something similar using pdflatex?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{epigrafica}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I add, instead, this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380848/use-epigrafica-font-for-sections-otherwise-newtxtext-newtxmath

Comment: The link that you share to me is not useful because I'm compiling in pdflatex instead pdftex. I tried it and doesn't work